# Is there something like a node supervisor "class" available?

Tags: ros, rosservice, rostopic, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want a process to control my nodes, starting
pausing, restarting, checking if it still is operational etc.
Like a library you add to the node doing that with services and
is able to set a value to disable the node from doing processing(by class::running() / class::paused()).

Is there something standardized like that already out there?

Regards,

Christian

---

I am going to implement something on my own, thanks everybody for your answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214912/is-there-something-like-a-node-supervisor-%22class%22-available?/) by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-30

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2015-07-30**:
I asked something similar (http://answers.ros.org/question/213509/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-respawn-property-at-runtime/) and got so far no answer. So I guess there is nothing like that. To get an overview over your nodes, you could have a look at http://wiki.ros.org/node_manager_fkie

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-30**:
Thanks, the software is awesome, not directly what I need but goes into the direction.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2022-01-06**:
See also #q360115, the answer there is to use ros1_lifecycle https://github.com/boschresearch/ros1_lifecycle (or my heavily modified version https://github.com/lucasw/ros1_lifecycle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably not the answer you're looking for, but in ROS 2 (think long term), it's very likely that nodes will have an (optional) standard lifecycle. See the proposed [node lifecycle](https://github.com/gbiggs/design/blob/gh-pages/articles/node_lifecycle.md) design document for more details. I believe the proposal addresses what you're asking for.

For ROS 1, i.e. now, there is no general out-of-the-box solution that I know of. I know some projects like `ros_control` implement [project-specific](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/blob/indigo-devel/controller_interface/include/controller_interface/controller_base.h#L58-L77) [solutions](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/blob/indigo-devel/controller_interface/include/controller_interface/controller_base.h#L128-L144). You might want to implement a custom solution.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-30**:
Yep currently not, ROS 2.0 is, not there yet. But the ros control is something I want to take a closer look at, but I guess it is not the thing I want right now. Currently its about getting status information and starting, pausing, restarting for all nodes not just hardware.Or I don't get the point?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you trying to do this management through code? Or are you looking for some kind of GUI? If you're looking for a GUI, have you seen [rqt_top?](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_top)

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2015-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-30**:
I am not looking for a GUI, I am looking for something which actually can start node and maybe add some stuff like services which are able to pause and resume node operation (not necessarily terminating it, but with that possibility), also being able to query its state and so on,Goal:Enduser product

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-30**:
On the "other end" there is a manager process checking states, pausing nodes when not needed to safe computation time.

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-30**:
I guess the source for rqt_top can come in handy when looking for active nodes, thanks.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2015-07-30**:
Also another option, you can use the regular command line tools from your code, like [rosnode kill](http://wiki.ros.org/rosnode#rosnode_kill) and [rosrun](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbash#rosrun). With python it would be like `import os os.system('rosnode kill nodename')`

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-30**:
Well I am not sure but I probably need it for CPP.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-07-30**:
@Airuno2L I think the OP wants to pause/stop the activity of a node without actually killing it. I can imagine usecases in which node setup and teardown are expensive in terms of time and computational resources. Navigation, motion planning or complex perception pipelines would be good exampels.

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-30**:
Correct. You got it. But also being able to stop and restart ;-)